# Current object in Enumerator

Tags: ruby, enumeration

`Enumerator#peek` returns next object in enumerator. But how to get current object?

I couldn't find any other solution than using index (for array).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like so:

```
enum = [1,2,3].to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each> 
enum.next #=> 1 
enum.peek #=> 2
enum.peek #=> 2 # to show enumerator is not incremented 
enum.next #=> 2 
enum.peek #=> 3 
enum.next #=> 3 
enum.peek #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

If you need to know the current value of the enumerator, after  executing`enum.next`, just save it to a variable: `curr = enum.next`. Enumerators are generally used with blocks, in which case the current value of the enumerator is assigned to the block variable.  To my knowledge, there is no way to obtain the current value of the enumerator from the enumerator object.